# RTL ActionBar Home Button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, right-to-left

I'm using below code in order to have **RTL ActionBar**. It works fine but there is a problem with **home icon**.

If I run my app in devices with Android V.5 (Lollipop), it's displayed correctly in both languages type (LTR & RTL)

If I run my app in devices with Android older than V.5, it's displayed correctly in RTL languages type, and incorrectly in LTR languages !!!

**RTLActionBar class**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public class SetActionBarRTL {

private Window window;
private Context context;

public SetActionBarRTL(Context context, Window window)
{
    this.window = window;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setActionBarRTL()
{
    int resId;
    ViewGroup actionBarView;

    View view = window.getDecorView();

    resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
            "action_bar", "id", context.getPackageName());
    actionBarView = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(resId);

    if (actionBarView == null)
    {
        resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
        actionBarView = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(resId);
    }
   actionBarView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

}
```

**myActivity**

```
public class myActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
   actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   SetActionBarRTL ac = new SetActionBarRTL(myActivity.this, window);
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    {
        ac.setActionBarRTL();
    }
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated ...

Comment: did you get any solution?